# Datatable -> Gridview persisting through postback when adding rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, viewstate

I am currently manually adding data to a datatable and then binding the datatable to a gridview one row at a time. However each postback when attempting to add a new row is overwriting the original row because a new datatable is created and bound each time.

How can I preserve the datatable in the View state and add to it, bind, and then preserve again so I can keep adding rows to the gridview? I am not familiar with the View State at all; I only know that it is what I want from googling around.

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLFirstColumn" runat="server" Style="z-index: 1; left: 11px;
    top: 171px; position: absolute; height: 16px; width: 104px">
    <asp:ListItem>Selection 1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Selection 2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Selection 3</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSecondColumn" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; left: 127px; top: 169px; position: absolute; height: 22px; width: 56px"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDLThirdColumn" runat="server" Style="z-index: 1; left: 200px; top: 171px;
    position: absolute">
    <asp:ListItem>Selection 1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Selection 2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Selection 3</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Button ID="btn_Add" runat="server" Style="z-index: 1; left: 345px; top: 167px;
    position: absolute" Text="Add" OnClick="btn_Add_Click" />
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Style="z-index: 1; left: 14px; top: 219px;
    position: absolute; width: 400px">
</asp:GridView>

using System;
using System.Data;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void btn_Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Column 1", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt.Columns.Add("Column 2", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt.Columns.Add("Column 3", Type.GetType("System.String"));

        dt.Columns[0].DefaultValue = DDLFirstColumn.SelectedValue;
        dt.Columns[1].DefaultValue = txtSecondColumn.Text;
        dt.Columns[2].DefaultValue = DDLThirdColumn.SelectedValue;

        dt.Rows.Add();

        GridView1.DataSource = dt;

        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the datatable in ViewState like:

```
 ViewState["dt"] = dt; // Store it in viewstate
```

Then you can access it from View State as follows:

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["dt"]; // Retrieving from ViewState 

protected void btn_Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
..............

dt.Rows.Add();

ViewState["dt"] = dt; // storing datatable in ViewState

GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
}
}
```

Comment: I tried the example you gave and I could not get it to work. I am probably missing something simple but I tried multiple arrangements and still nothing. I did however find a working solution at http://www.dotnetobject.com/showthread.php?tid=1286  

Thanks for the help though.

Comment: The question you have asked, how store and retrieve from ViewState. What you have missed is, when you are trying to add value second time, you have to get the value from ViewState instead from new datatable.